# "/proc/partitions not found" error is showing up

Tags: command-line, 10.04, files

I am configuring a webserver in Ubuntu 10.04. More particularly I am installing [DataStax OpsCenter](http://www.datastax.com/products/opscenter).

Unfortunately, the logs are spammed with this error:

```
ERROR [pool-3-thread-7] 2013-02-15 22:04:34,533 Long os-stats collector failed: Process failed: cat /proc/partitions
  Exit val: 1
  Output:
cat: /proc/partitions: No such file or directory
ERROR [pool-5-thread-3] 2013-02-15 22:04:56,846 Error getting devices and partitions #<IOException java.io.IOException: Process failed: cat /proc/partitions
  Exit val: 1
  Output:
cat: /proc/partitions: No such file or directory>
```

Why do I get `cat: /proc/partitions: No such file or directory`?

I really doubt that the problem is with the application I am using, because if I run this command from command line `cat /proc/partitions` I still get `No such file or directory` and from what I have found in some forums that directory should be created when the OS is starting up, I could be wrong but that's as far I got.

Comment: Hello Linas and welcome on Ask Ubuntu ! Could you please tell again what version of Ubuntu you are using (10.04 or 12.04) ? Furthermore, could you tell us what you try to install and what tutorial you are following ? Usually, "No such file or directory" means that the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @Agmenor please see my updated question

Comment: When you reboot -- and before opening DataStax OpsCenter -- does `/proc/partions` exist?

Comment: @chaskes no it doesn't

Comment: Are you using a VPS? Does `/proc/diskstats` exist?

Comment: @qbi Yes I am using VPS, and not that dir do not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your comment, you're on a virtual private server (VPS). OpenVZ as well as other VPS solutions don't offer access to `/proc/partitions`. The whole `/proc` partition is a virtual filesystem ([procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)). The structure is maintained in the kernel. So it will not work to manually create the file.

The DataStax OpsCenter has a support forum. At the moment I found no questions qhich deal with your problem. However the experts there should be able to help you out.

Comment: Well that explains it, i will try my luck there then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get proc file system you might need to mount it.

```
mount proc /proc
```

To get list of partitions I use following commands. Each of them gives list of partitions.

```
fdisk -l 
parted -l
df -h
mount
```

Note: `mount` only displays list of volumes currently mounted and `df` shows statistics of mounted volumes.

---

Answer created by @Shiplu in a [Stack Overflow tread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12551673).

Comment: Just tried that and it says `proc already mounted`

Answer (score -1):

Try making the folder yourself. This is how you do it: in a terminal, type

```
sudo mkdir /proc
sudo mkdir /proc/partitions
```

See if your logs still appear.

Comment: Just tried that and got this: ` cannot create directory `partitions': No such file or directory` however i can create this dir anywhere else

Comment: I updated the answer, can you say whether the /proc/partitions folder then exists ?

Comment: tried to run both commands, for the first one it says that /proc dir already exists and for the second one i still get `cannot create directory /proc/partitions': No such file or directory`

Answer (score -3):

Installation steps to install pro* C / proc / pro c 
SK Vandeyaer 
download all this software for windows 32 bit from oracle site :

```
instantclient-basiclite-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-jdbc-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-odbc-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-precomp-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-precomp-win32-11.1.0.7.0
instantclient-sdk-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-sqlplus-nt-12.1.0.1.0
instantclient-tools-nt-12.1.0.1.0
```

Extract all to a single folder ... keep all the contents under a single folder.
check if `proc.exe` and `oci.dll` are in same folder **otherwise it will error out.

run the proc program from command prompt

1. start -> run -> cmd
2. `cd c:\singlefolder`   (contents where all the extracted contents are present)
3. type `proc` - it should give out some output (if you get its installed correctly)
4. to run - type `proc progamname.pc`
5. check the same folder it should have generated a `programname.c` file in same directory
6. you can run the `.c` file using vc++ or any c++ compiler (borland or others)

Sample program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
    getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it applies on this website - you're on Ask Ubuntu here and your answer is Windows specific.